# Tag names for EXIF?

Tags: swift, tags, exif

I'm trying to extract data from EXIF tag. I'm able to get the date, but some tags seems to use different tag names:

```
let cgref = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(NSURL.fileURL(withPath: polkuz) as CFURL, nil)

let imaprop2: NSDictionary = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(cgref!, 0, nil)!

let exif: NSDictionary? = imaprop2["{Exif}"] as! NSDictionary?

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss" 
    var pictureDate : Date

    let time0z: String? = exif!["DateTimeOriginal"] as! String?
    if time0z != nil {
        print("DateTimeOriginal = \(time0z!)")
        if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: time0z!) {
            pictureDate = date
        }
    }

// doesn't work!!!

    let model: String? = exif!["Model"] as! String?
    if model != nil {
        print("model = \(model!)")
    }
}
```

This code works for the date.
How do I get the correct spelling of the other tags like model, artist or author?